# Why harmony.json file is used in Ethereum Blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

What are the roles of harmony.json file is used in Ethereum Blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly referring to the genesis configuration export, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/cc606be74c6f1f05b0b0a6226a400e734b9aac31/cmd/puppeth/wizard_genesis.go#L193) in go-ethereum.

With a network name of 'Ethereum' for example, go-ethereum exports the following genesis files :

- Ethereum.json : Geth / Puppeth clients compatible genesis file
- Ethereum-aleth.json : Aleth client compatible genesis file
- Ethereum-parity.json : Parity client compatible genesis file
- Ethereum-harmony.json : Harmony client compatible genesis file

That way, if you create a new blockchain using go-ethereum, you have compatibility with those other main client implementations straight out of the box, as you can provide them with a genesis file in the format they expect. Therefore, people running those other clients can connect to your new network with ease.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Actually how far I know, genesis.jsoon file for genesis node and carry information about the network, other node in the same network initiate with the same genesis.json. But my question is why harmony.json is used and what is it's specific purpose.

Comment: They are just genesis.json in the format that other client implementations (such as harmony) expects. Geth doesn't make any use of it as far as I know. It would be used by the harmony client for example to connect to the network / blockchain you created with geth.